# similarity/distance measurement between two ranked sequence

Tags: algorithms, data-analysis

Is there an efficient way to measure similarity/distance between two sequences of ranked numbers/letters. The two sequences are of different length, and only have some elements in common?

For example, if I have three rank ordered numeric sequences like this:

sequence A: 1,2,3,4,5,6

sequence B: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

sequence C: 6,3,4,2,5,8,7,10,9

Intuitively, I guess sequence A and B are more similar, since they have more numbers in common and the common numbers have same order in both sequences. Sequence A and C are less similar since they have less number in common and the common numbers have difference orders in each sequence. Damerau-Levenshtein Distance seems to be an ok option, it measures the similarity between two strings of letters, which considers insertion, deletion, substitution and adjacent transposition of letters. But I also want to consider non-adjacent transposition, i.e., more that two letters between two swapped letters. For example, in sequence C above, '2' and '6' are swapped, but they are not adjacent letters since there are '3' and '4' in between them. Damerau-Levenshtein Distance doesn't seem to take this into account.

Comment: Just to push this ... I would be very interested in an answer to that, maybe  http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23455/similarity-of-two-csv-files-or-more is related?

Comment: There are some distance metrics specifically for time series. Dynamic time warping or move split merge

Answer (score 1):

As a starter, I would use the cost of bringing the elements into the same order.  Of course this ignores the insertion of missing elements.

A simple solution would be insertion sort:

```
6,3 move 3 1 ahead => cost 1.
3,6,4 move 4 1 ahead => cost 1+1.
3,4,6,2 move 2 3 ahead => cost 1+1+3.
2,3,4,6,5 move 5 1 ahead => cost 1+1+3+1.
2,3,4,5,6,8 correct => cost 1+1+3+1.
2,3,4,5,6,8,7 move 7 1 ahead => cost 1+1+3+1+1.
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10 correct => cost 1+1+3+1+1.
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,9 move 9 1 ahead => cost 1+1+3+1+1+1=8.
```

The algorithmic complexity would be $O(n^2)$.

A more efficient way would be to precompute the desired position for each element using an associative map and computing the distance.  The result will be slightly different from the above.

```
mapB={0: 2, 1: 3, ...}
cost( 6)=abs(4-0)=4
cost( 3)=abs(1-1)=0
cost( 4)=abs(2-2)=0
cost( 2)=abs(0-3)=3
cost( 5)=abs(3-4)=1
cost( 8)=abs(6-5)=1
cost( 7)=abs(5-6)=1
cost(10)=abs(8-7)=1
cost( 9)=abs(7-8)=1
total=12
```

Using an ordered map (tree), ignoring rotations, would give $O(2n\log(n))=O(n\log(n))$.  Using a hash table, ignoring collisions, would give $O(2n)=O(n)$.

Now, we would have to handle the insertion of missing elements.  The second algorithm, allows us to count elements present in the second sequence but not present in the first (`seq2only`).  If we eliminate/mark elements we have encountered in the first sequence, we can easily count elements present in the first sequence but not in the second (`seq1only`).  The penalty for those would be `insertioncost*(seq2only+seq1only)`.